# RFID software for windows, linux and Mac

Tags: open-source, rfid

I want to learn how to play with RFID... Read it, write it, scan for it.
I need the software to do this as well as the hardware. 
I'm not 100% sure what my end goal is. So, the more sources is get, the better. Keep the comments coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have these options to use for your requirement:
Tikitag RFID Programming Kit http://www.jeremyperson.com/tikitag-rfid-programming-kit/ or this RFID Programming Kit http://www.phidgets.com/products.php?category=14

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

The actual hardware to read tags is not so complicated. You can get a reader like [this one](http://www.parallax.com/tabid/768/ProductID/517/Default.aspx) that can read tags fairly simply. The scanner just sends a unique 10 byte code every time it reads a tag, and you can handle that in just about any software fairly trivially.

I have never written tags because I have never found a need to. You can get tags for under a dollar each, and they all have a unique key. I just record them into my system and store them.

I use rfid for a basic entry control system on my front door, using an arduino controller to send the codes to my central server, and then to open an electronic lock. My setup is sort of similar to what is described [here.](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-RFID-Door-Lock/) My server allows me to remotely access it, and to set up specific time based access restrictions for individual tags. The microcontroller is not strictly required, but it allows me an easy way to interface with various hardware elements.

Comment: http://www.gumbolabs.org/2009/10/17/parallax-rfid-reader-arduino/ also gives a pretty good idea of what kind of protocol you are dealing with. Its really quite simple.